# Qual a definição correta de concatenação e o que realmente acontece quando fazemos isso com variáveis?

Tags: teoria-da-computação, portugol-studio

Estou aprendendo programação por conta própria e confesso ainda estar no início. Utilizando Portugol Studio, aprendi um pouco sobre concatenação e, a princípio, foi algo que pareceu simples. O conceito inicial dado a mim foi **união de duas ou mais strings**, o que eu julguei como certo, já que realmente fazia sentido durante alguns instantes. Pensei que teria outra maneira de executar cálculos com variáveis numéricas, já que a concatenação deveria transformá-las em um conjunto de caracteres, mas não foi o caso para mim.

```
programa
{
    
    funcao inicio()
    {
        real pi = 3.14
        escreva("O número pi tem uma seríe infinita de algarismos decimais, mas pode é comumente resumido em ", pi, "\n")
        escreva("A maioria das cálculadoras científicas aproxima pi para ", pi+0.0015926,"\n")
        escreva("3,14"+"0.0015926")
    }
}
```

O algorítimo teve três saídas diferentes: 
**3.14 (valor original); 

3.1415925 (valor obtido através de uma soma entre números com ponto flutuante); 

3.140.0015926 (valor obtido através da junção de duas strings).**

Já que concatenação é uma junção de duas strings, por que a segunda saída de dados retornou uma soma de duas variáveis do tipo real e não o que aconteceu no terceiro?

Entendo que, para uma variável ser transformada em string, ela deveria ser colocada entre aspas, mas se elas não são automaticamente transformadas durante uma concatenação, isso quebraria o conceito de **"união entre duas ou mais strings"**. Então, **qual o real conceito de concatenação e o que acontece quando concatenamos variáveis?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinícius, suas próprias perguntas e código respondem por si:

- *"Por que a segunda saída de dados retornou uma soma de duas variáveis do tipo real?"*
  Veja o código: `pi+0.0015926` aqui **não há strings**, há uma variável numérica (`Real`) e um valor, logo é feita a soma, não há concatenação aqui.
- *"E não o que aconteceu no terceiro?"*
  Veja o código: `"3,14"+"0.0015926"` aqui **são duas strings** por isso aconteceu a concatenação.
- *"Entendo que, para uma variável ser transformada em string, ela deveria ser colocada entre aspas, mas se elas não são automaticamente transformadas durante uma concatenação..."*  este conceito está **parcialmente** correto, isso depende da linguagem. A maioria das linguagens não vai aceitar algo como `"1" + 1` ou `3.14 + "2.2"`, por não ser possível concatenar os tipos diferentes. Isso vai gerar um erro e vai ser preciso usar uma função de conversão, ou converter os dois para string para ocorrer a concatenação, ou para número, para ocorrer a soma, mas algumas linguagens simplesmente fazem a conversão "automática" ai, por isso precisa se atentar para esses casos.

Sobre o tema da pergunta em sim, o termo "concatenação", usado no contexto de computação é realmente o processo de "juntar" strings, como pode ser visto no Wiki: [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

> Concatenação é um termo usado em computação para designar a operação
> de unir o conteúdo de duas strings. Por exemplo, considerando as
> strings "casa" e "mento" a concatenação da primeira com a segunda gera
> a string "casamento".

Ou seja, para que ocorra a concatenação, todos os valores (pode mais de 2) devem ser do tipo string. No seu segundo caso não há strings, então ocorre a operação de soma.

Comment: Me sinto muito feliz que dois profissionais experientes responderam minha pergunta quase que ao mesmo tempo. Receber a ajuda de vocês dois dobrou meus ânimos com o estudo de programação. Tenho só mais uma dúvida que acho justo perguntar a você, já que foi a primeira entre as duas respostas. Com o operador de concatenação "," no portugol, eu posso fazer algo assim: escreva(o resultado da sua adição foi: ", resultadoAdicao), mas o certo seria dividir isso em duas saídas de dados, certo? Uma para cada tipo.

Comment: obrigado pelo feedback @ViníciusMagalhães. Sobre o escreva, a "," lá não é bem um operador para concatenar, ele serve para receber "uma lista de parâmetros", então um `escreva("A soma é: ", x+y)` funciona. Como é um comando/função para escrever no console, internamente ele pode até converter para string, mas não antes de fazer aperação, por isso a vírgula não é bem para concatenar, mas para passar uma lista de parametros para serem escritos :) bons estudos

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro leia isto: [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

Você não soma ou concatena ou faz qualquer operação com variáveis, mas sim faz com valores, que eventualmente estão armazenados em variáveis ou em objetos que são referenciadas por variáveis. Sem conceituar certo não dá para aprender corretamente, e parece que quer aprender o correto.

A questão da diferença de resultado seria estranha para quem nunca ouviu falar de concatenação, mas é auto explicativo quando se sabe o que é.

Quando se aplica o operador `+` em valores numéricos ele faz uma soma matemática que todo mundo conhece. Quando se aplica o mesmo operador à textos ele faz a tal da concatenação, ou seja, junta dois textos e cria um novo com tudo junto.

O segundo caso tem valores numéricos, por que ele faria uma concatenação com isso? Seria estranho.

Então variáveis não são transformadas em *strings* ou qualquer outra coisa, pelo já exposto acima.

Para transformar um valor numérico não se coloca entre aspas, se colocar aspas então o que tem ali é um texto, uma *string*, não é um valor numérico transformado. E se não tem aspas não é um texto é um valor numérico ou outro tipo que tenha um literal definido pela linguagem.

O literal que tem um ou uma sequência de dígitos numéricos indica um valor quantitativo. O literal que começa e termina com aspas indica uma descrição de alguma coisa, um texto.

Quando concatena valores, e isso só acontece em valores do tipo `string`, cada caractere de do segundo valor vai sendo colocando em sequência logo após os caracteres existentes do primeiro valor. A forma exata como isso acontece na memória parece ser algo irrelevante no momento já que é o conhecimento mais aprofundado e que em geral o programador não precisa entender, até estar mais avançado e desejar dominar tudo.

Tem linguagem, até bem popular que bagunça isso quando mistura um texto um um número, mas vamos trabalhar com a ideia de uma linguagem que não faz coisas malucas.